# Bound wildcard in generic field

Tags: java, generics

For example I have these generic classes:

```
class Base<A, B extends Base<?, B>> {}
class SubA extends Base<String, SubA> {} // B = own type
class SubB extends Base<String, SubB> {} // B = own type
class SubC extends Base<String, SubA> {} // B != own type
```

Here comes the problem: How do I store (as class field / variable) a list of *particular* subclass of `Base` objects such that the `B` type is the subclass type (i.e. only allow `List<SubA>` *or* `List<SubB>` but not `List<SubC>`)?

The method equivalent is:

```
public <T extends Base<?, T>> List<T> getList() {}
```

However, there is no way to declare a variable with that `T` there. How should I go about fixing this?

#### Edit

(Edit 2: I have fixed the sample codes because I made some mistakes while I wrote those without IDE)

After reading Andy's comment, I think this example is not *really* accurate to express the issue I am facing. I'll give a more accurate example (though the example may not looks like a sane idea).

```
abstract class Wrapper<T, W extends Wrapper<T, W>> {
    public abstract W wrap(T original);
    public abstract T unwrap(W wrapper);
}
abstract class NumberWrapper<T extends Number, W extends NumberWrapper<T, W> extends Wrapper<T, W> {
    public final Number getNumber() {
        return unwrap();
    }
}
class IntegerWrapper extends NumberWrapper<Integer, IntegerWrapper> {}
class DoubleWrapper extends NumberWrapper<Double, DoubleWrapper> {}
class LongWrapper extends NumberWrapper<Long, LongWrapper> {}

abstract class ValuePrinter<T> {
    public abstract void printValue(T value);
}

class Foo {
    private ValuePrinter<NumberWrapper<?, ?>> printer = new ValuePrinter<NumberWrapper<?, ?>>() {
        @Override public void printValue(NumberWrapper<?, ?> value) {
            Number num = value.getNumber();
            System.out.println(num); // Don't ask why this is done
        }
    };

    public ValuePrinter<NumberWrapper<?, ?>> getPrinter() { return printer; }
}

/**
 * A scheduler that prints value once every 5 seconds.
 */
static class Scheduler<T> {
    private LinkedList<T> printingQueue;
    private final ValuePrinter<T> printer;

    public Scheduler(ValuePrinter<T> printer) {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public void scheduleToPrint(List<T> toPrint) {
        printingQueue.addAll(toPrint);
        startIfNotStarted();
    }
}

class Test {
    private List<DoubleWrapper> doubleWrappers;
    private List<IntegerWrapper> intWrappers;
    private Foo foo;

    public void scheduledPrintDoubles() {
        new Scheduler<>().scheduleToPrint(doubleWrappers, foo.getPrinter()); // Compile error
    }
}
```

This new example may not make sense, but it describes the problem I'm facing. I have declared `printer` as `ValuePrinter<NumberWrapper<?, ?>>` because that's the most convenient.

However, calling `Scheduler.getInstance().scheduleToPrint(w, Foo::printValue)` is going to give me compile-time error because it expects `w` to be the exact same type as the consumer defined in `Foo::printValue`, which causes a type mismatch between `DoubleWrapper` (which is a `NumberWrapper<?, ? extends NumberWrapper>`) and `NumberWrapper<?, ?>` for the bound type `T` specified in `scheduleToPrint`.

This is the compile error my Eclipse IDE shows:

```
The method scheduleToPrint(List<NumberWrapper<?,?>>) in the type 
Scheduler<NumberWrapper<?,?>> is not applicable for the arguments 
(List<DoubleWrapper>)
```

Comment: "How do I store ... a list of particular subclass of Base objects" Same way you store a list of a particular subclass of `Object`: you declare the field to have the type you want. A `List<A>` field can't contain a `List<B>` or a `List<C>`.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. Everything compiles fine for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: @KamilJarosz Updated again. The code wasn't quite right because I wrote without IDE.

Comment: Interesting question! I like tricky generic types. There still seems to be some problem with the code, and the code doesn't correspond to the text. I think you have updated some parts of it but not other. Example: The declaration of `scheduleToPrint` and the call to it, the declaration of `Foo` and the reference in the text to `Foo::printValue`.

Comment: The compilation error that you give in the end of the question ("`The method scheduleToPrint(List<NumberWrapper<?,?>>) `") can be resolved by giving `scheduleToPrint` the following signature: `public void scheduleToPrint(List<? extends T> toPrint)`. That works for the given code, but I don't know if it really solves you problem.

Comment: @Lii I think this works... But I'm not too sure if it'd fix mine because I have split mine into concrete types.

Comment: Could you fix your code so that it could compile? There's no `scheduleToPrint` method that takes 2 arguments, class cannot be static, missing `>`, invalid `unwrap()` call, not overriding abstract methods etc. I'd like to help but I can't even reproduce your problem. You could post a minimal _working_ example.